# pl sql - PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'DISPLAY'

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I'm having to create a procedure and make `num1` (which = 5) and `num2` (which = 3) input parameters instead of declaring them as variables and then assign those values in parenthesis to them.

I have a 3rd variable (`num3`) which is the result of `num1^num2`(5^3) which is 125.
This pl/sql statement has to be executed as `exec my_power( 5, 3);`

I'm getting the `PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'DISPLAY'`

Here is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE display
( 
num1 IN NUMBER,
num2 IN NUMBER,
num3 IN OUT NUMBER
)
AS
BEGIN
  num3 := num1**num2;
  dbms_output.put_line('num3 = '|| (num1**num2));
END;
/
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
EXEC display (5, 3);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your procedure requires 3 arguments, but in your call, you provide only two. Change your calling code to

```
Declare
  result number;
begin
  display (5, 3, result);
end;
```

and it should work.

*UPDATE*

You declared a procedure with two IN parameters and one IN OUT parameter - all of them mandatory. Therefore, Oracle requires you to call your procedure with three parameters. You might be tempted to try

`display(5,3,8);`

but this won't work, either - your 3rd parameter is IN OUT, and Oracle needs you to provide a variable where it can store the value you assign to num3 in your procedure.

But you don't really need the 3rd parameter if you only want to print the result of your calculation - change your procedure to

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE display
(
  num1 IN NUMBER,
  num2 IN NUMBER
)
AS
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line('num3 = '|| (num1**num2));
END;
```

Then, you can call it with

```
EXEC display (5, 3);
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you please provide an example?

Comment: @rls1982: Frank's answer **is** an example.

Comment: @rls1982 Not sure what you mean by "provide an example". I've added an explanation plus an alternative implementation without IN OUT parameters.

Comment: Thanks. 

It took a while for my page to refresh and for me to see this.

Answer (score -1):

Wrong, please try

```
declare 
nu number;
begin
  display(2, 3, nu);
  dbms_output.put_line(nu);  
end;
```

Comment: I have to declare num1 and num2 as input variables.
Could you please elaborate?
Thanks for your help